# If page does not load properly, how to refresh

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, page-refresh

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/a[contains(text(),'Seller Catalog')]")).click();`

In my code, if I execute the above line sometimes, it's displayed next page properly, but sometime it's displayed blank page.

Next page content below element. 
`//div/label[contains(text(),'Document Type')]`

I need to refresh the page, only if blank page display, else continue the code.
Even I try bellow scenario, it wasn't success.

```
if (!driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div/label[contains(text(),'Document Type')]")).isEmpty()) {        
    driver.navigate().refresh();
} else {
    // DO SOMETHING ELSE 
}
```

Is there any other way to complete this?

Thanks ..

Comment: Remove the `!` in your `if` statement or it won't refresh if the elements aren't found.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with the website and/or environment and not simply a refresh issue.  If you insist of having the automation work around this (which I don't recommend), you will most likely need to detect you have come to a blank page by possibly searching for an expected element like you are above and then navigate back to the original URL and try again.  Like I said though, I wouldn't recommend this because you are just masking the problem, but that is one way around it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
When I manually do this, page loaded properly. issue is coming only with automation process. 
Also when I try to search expected element, it given "no such element: Unable to locate element:"